# SQL Regex Constraint for Emojis

Tags: sql, postgresql, emoji

We are looking to store emojis in a database table.  Emojis are just text (Unicode glyphs), so some kind of validation would be required to identify that only an emoji ('') is added and not another text-character ('Random words') was entered.

Does anyone have validation for emojis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Intro

A few things to note up-front:

1. The official emoji set has continued to evolve, since v1, back in 2015.  At the time of this posting, the [latest official release is v14](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts-14.0/full-emoji-list.html).
2. As part of the Unicode standard, emojis are glyphs.  But one emoji glyph is not always created by one Unicode character.  As the releases have come along, more and more emojis are created by the **adjoining of multiple Unicode values, to account for skin-tone, gender, hair-type, and other variants**.
3. Proposed **short name and short codes can be library-specific**, which may support aliases or alternative names.  Storing the Unicode characters that compose the emoji glyph simplifies this architectural-fragility, though it then places more ownership on front-end libraries for efforts like grouping skin-tone variants together.
4. [The emoji set reuses some existing Unicode glyphs](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-variants.html), like the black "heart suit" (♥), adding a variant selector to make them officially part of the emoji set (❤️).  This means that a number of the **emoji characters are non-sequential**, as they were added to the Unicode standard before emojis existed.
5. Many systems have their own **emoji outliers that are not part of the official standard**.  These are not included in this work, though if they are comprised of multiple Unicode values, they may still pass the proposed validation.

#### Proposed Solution

After scraping [the codes of the current list](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts-14.0/full-emoji-list.html), and adding the [Zero Width Joiner](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-zwj-sequences.html) and all component glyphs, I suggest the following check.

```sql
alter table emojis add constraint emojis__emoji_regex_ck check (value ~ '^[\U00000023,\U0000002A,\U00000030-\U00000039,\U000000A9,\U000000AE,\U0000200D,\U0000203C,\U00002049,\U00002122,\U00002139,\U00002194-\U00002199,\U000021A9-\U000021AA,\U0000231A-\U0000231B,\U00002328,\U000023CF,\U000023E9-\U000023F3,\U000023F8-\U000023FA,\U000024C2,\U000025AA-\U000025AB,\U000025B6,\U000025C0,\U000025FB-\U000025FE,\U00002600-\U00002604,\U0000260E,\U00002611,\U00002614-\U00002615,\U00002618,\U0000261D,\U00002620,\U00002622-\U00002623,\U00002626,\U0000262A,\U0000262E-\U0000262F,\U00002638-\U0000263A,\U00002640,\U00002642,\U00002648-\U00002653,\U0000265F-\U00002660,\U00002663,\U00002665-\U00002666,\U00002668,\U0000267B,\U0000267E-\U0000267F,\U00002692-\U00002697,\U00002699,\U0000269B-\U0000269C,\U000026A0-\U000026A1,\U000026A7,\U000026AA-\U000026AB,\U000026B0-\U000026B1,\U000026BD-\U000026BE,\U000026C4-\U000026C5,\U000026C8,\U000026CE-\U000026CF,\U000026D1,\U000026D3-\U000026D4,\U000026E9-\U000026EA,\U000026F0-\U000026F5,\U000026F7-\U000026FA,\U000026FD,\U00002702,\U00002705,\U00002708-\U0000270D,\U0000270F,\U00002712,\U00002714,\U00002716,\U0000271D,\U00002721,\U00002728,\U00002733-\U00002734,\U00002744,\U00002747,\U0000274C,\U0000274E,\U00002753-\U00002755,\U00002757,\U00002763-\U00002764,\U00002795-\U00002797,\U000027A1,\U000027B0,\U000027BF,\U00002934-\U00002935,\U00002B05-\U00002B07,\U00002B1B-\U00002B1C,\U00002B50,\U00002B55,\U00003030,\U0000303D,\U00003297,\U00003299, \U0000FE0F, \U0001F004,\U0001F0CF,\U0001F170-\U0001F171,\U0001F17E-\U0001F17F,\U0001F18E,\U0001F191-\U0001F19A,\U0001F1E6-\U0001F1FF,\U0001F201-\U0001F202,\U0001F21A,\U0001F22F,\U0001F232-\U0001F23A,\U0001F250-\U0001F251,\U0001F300-\U0001F321,\U0001F324-\U0001F393,\U0001F396-\U0001F397,\U0001F399-\U0001F39B,\U0001F39E-\U0001F3F0,\U0001F3F3-\U0001F3F5,\U0001F3F7-\U0001F4FD,\U0001F4FF-\U0001F53D,\U0001F549-\U0001F54E,\U0001F550-\U0001F567,\U0001F56F-\U0001F570,\U0001F573-\U0001F57A,\U0001F587,\U0001F58A-\U0001F58D,\U0001F590,\U0001F595-\U0001F596,\U0001F5A4-\U0001F5A5,\U0001F5A8,\U0001F5B1-\U0001F5B2,\U0001F5BC,\U0001F5C2-\U0001F5C4,\U0001F5D1-\U0001F5D3,\U0001F5DC-\U0001F5DE,\U0001F5E1,\U0001F5E3,\U0001F5E8,\U0001F5EF,\U0001F5F3,\U0001F5FA-\U0001F64F,\U0001F680-\U0001F6C5,\U0001F6CB-\U0001F6D2,\U0001F6D5-\U0001F6D7,\U0001F6DD-\U0001F6E5,\U0001F6E9,\U0001F6EB-\U0001F6EC,\U0001F6F0,\U0001F6F3-\U0001F6FC,\U0001F7E0-\U0001F7EB,\U0001F7F0,\U0001F90C-\U0001F93A,\U0001F93C-\U0001F945,\U0001F947-\U0001F9FF,\U0001FA70-\U0001FA74,\U0001FA78-\U0001FA7C,\U0001FA80-\U0001FA86,\U0001FA90-\U0001FAAC,\U0001FAB0-\U0001FABA,\U0001FAC0-\U0001FAC5,\U0001FAD0-\U0001FAD9,\U0001FAE0-\U0001FAE7,\U0001FAF0-\U0001FAF6]+$');
```

#### Caveats

It is not bullet-proof.  For instance:

- This only validates that all characters are from the emoji set, not that they combine to form one valid/recognized emoji glyph.
- This allows multiple emojis to be entered into the same field.  [The largest combination of emoji glyphs that I found was 10](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/14.0/emoji-test.txt), but even a max-length of 10 characters would not stop 10 thumbs-up emojis from being entered into the same field.
- You could make this validation regex smaller by closing some of the gaps in the ranges.  For instance, the [legacy "white club suit" glyph](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2667) (♧) is not part of the current emoji spec, but those glyphs around it are.

This list will have to be updated, once v15 and beyond are released.  But this should be a start.  **This was all self-researched, so if I missed anything, mislabelled anything, overstated anything, or just plain got it wrong, please comment below.**